# Where can I buy a transparent frying pan?

Tags: frying, pan, frying-pan

Where could I find a transparent frying pan?

[image: frying pan]

Comment: What do you mean by this? A frying pan made of glass? The only transparent things I've used for actual cooking are glass casseroles similar to [this one](http://www.collectionsetc.com/Product/glass-casserole-pot.aspx), and you'll find these in any decent cookery shop.

Comment: Yes, something like this but it is a frying pan. Maybe made of glass or other material.

Comment: Yikes. Don't stoves usually provide heat that's too uneven and would tend to stress and break glass?

Comment: That was for filming purposes. Heat and glass don't go so well together.

Comment: @tom: not true, what about the glass ovenware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just search on www.ebay.com for "Pyrex Flameware" and you will find things like :

[Vintage Pyrex Flameware Saucepan Skillet + Handle SET](http://cgi.ebay.de/Vintage-Pyrex-Flameware-Saucepan-Skillet-Handle-SET-/380077012073?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item587e5af469#ht_2685wt_905)

[Vintage Pyrex Glass Flameware Skillet w/ Handles](http://cgi.ebay.de/Vintage-Pyrex-Glass-Flameware-Skillet-w-Handles-/120760570549?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c1de412b5#ht_1168wt_905)

[1930's Pyrex Flameware saute pan w/ detachable handle](http://cgi.ebay.de/1930s-Pyrex-Flameware-saute-pan-w-detachable-handle-/280723346954?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item415c6a560a#ht_500wt_1156)

It is highly unlikely that you will find a new one. The reason is that the formula r for Pyrex before 1940 was way more resistant to thermal shock , but also more expensive. The current formula is more resistant to mechanical shocks but can not take rapid cooling (like adding cold liquid in a hot pan when you are making a ragu) without shattering.

I have no info on the advantages of a glass pan except the "cool factor"

Hope this info helps.

Comment: Before investing in Pyrex, read the answers to this question on whether one can use Pyrex on the stovetop http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17970/is-pyrex-safe-to-use-on-a-gas-burner

Answer (score 7):

Corning made a Visions pan - I had a set and used it for years. You might find them on eBay or at a garage sale. I didn't really like it as a pan - took a long time to heat up and then stayed hot, thus making a gas stove into an electric and making an electric even less responsive. It's not completely clear, it's kind of brownish.

[image]